# if statement to show 1 or 2 in database MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement

i cant seem to work out the logic to show as 1 or 2 in database depending on if there is any data.

the code is this :

In the model the logic is :

```
[Display(Name = "Mono Reading:")]
public double? MonoReading { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Colour Reading:")]
public double? ColourReading { get; set; }

public ReadingsEntry(string serialNumber) : this()
{
    //
    MonoReading = ca.vw_ReadingsEntry.Where(s => s.ser_num == SerialNumber && s.meter_type == "Mono").Select(c => c.meter_count).FirstOrDefault();
    ColourReading = ca.vw_ReadingsEntry.Where(s => s.ser_num == SerialNumber && s.meter_type == "Colour").Select(c => c.meter_count).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Html view:

```
<div id=”mono”>
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonoReading)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonoReading, new { @class = "form",})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MonoReading)
</div>
<div id=”colour”>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColourReading)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ColourReading, new { @class = "form", })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ColourReading)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(M2CustomerPortal.Areas.Customer.Models.ReadingsEntry.ReadingsEntry readingForm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newMeterReading = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.CustomerReadingsEntry();

        newMeterReading.ser_num = readingForm.SerialNumber;
        **newMeterReading.MeterReading =  // Logic to go here**

        cpctx.CustomerReadingsEntries.Add(newMeterReading);
        cpctx.SaveChanges();  
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What I am looking to do is if there is any data for `MonoReading` it should show as 1 for `newMeterReading.MeterReading` and `ColourReading` as 2.

How will the logic work in here:

```
newMeterReading.ser_num = readingForm.SerialNumber;
**newMeterReading.MeterReading =  // Logic to go here**
```

as you can see the example for `serialNumber` it returns serial number to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that

```
var newMeterReading = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.CustomerReadingEntry();
```

should be

```
var newMeterReading = new M2CPDAL.Models.CustomerPortal.ReadingEntry(readingForm.SerialNumber);
```

? And assuming that `MonoReading` and `ColourReading` are all accessible in the controller. I'm also assuming that having no data means 0 for the readings.

If so, you can do something like this:

```
bool hasMonoReading = MonoReading.GetValueOrDefault() > 0;
bool hasColourReading = ColourReading.GetValueOrDefault() > 0;
int readingValue = 0;
if (hasColourReading)
  readingValue = 2;
else if (hasMonoReading)
  readingValue = 1;
else
  readingValue = 0;
newMeterReading.MeterReading = readingValue;
```

or more succinctly:

```
bool hasMonoReading = MonoReading.GetValueOrDefault() > 0;
bool hasColourReading = ColourReading.GetValueOrDefault() > 0;
newMeterReading.MeterReading = (hasColourReading) ? 2 : (hasMonoReading) ? 1 : 0;
```

If no reading means the reading value is null, then you can do this:

```
newMeterReading.MeterReading = (ColourReading.HasValue) ? 2 : (MonoReading.HasValue) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and effort to answer the question. it has really helped me.